Update the table based on the 1st 3 rownum of unique Id
I need your help. I want to create a script to update the flag to 'X' where

flag is 'No' and
get the first 3 rownum of unique Id. E.g.

tablename: TBL_INFO
Sample table:
-------------------------
ID      |   FLAG
-------------------------
123     |   No
456     |   Yes
789     |   No
123     |   No
123     |   Yes
456     |   Yes
789     |   No
789     |   Yes
574     |   No
574     |   No
012     |   No

The sample table contains 5 distinct IDs (012, 123, 456, 574, 789) but since the problem is to update only the records where flag is 'No' and rownum of unique Ids is less than or equal to 3.
I am using oracle sql developer and I tried to create a script something like this:
UPDATE TBL_INFO 
SET FLAG='X'
WHERE FLAG='No' and rownum <= 3 order by ID.

This script is only updating the 1st 3 records.
-------------------------
ID      |   FLAG
-------------------------
012     |   X
123     |   X
123     |   X

Expected output:
-------------------------
ID      |   FLAG
-------------------------
012     |   X
123     |   X
123     |   X
574     |   X
574     |   X
456     |   Yes
789     |   No
789     |   Yes

I am having a hard time analyzing how to get the rownum of unique IDs if it is less than/equal to 3.
Thank you.

and rownum of unique Ids is less than or equal to 3 With what ordering?

I am using oracle sql developer Does your DBMS is MySQL which is set in tags list? Maybe you use OracleDB?

@Pinky your expected output does not contains all data. Please correct output

Expected output should be: https://i.sstatic.net/TXkw9dJj.png @Pinky  I have post my answer. Please check

UPDATE TBL_INFO 
   SET FLAG='X'
 WHERE FLAG='No'
   AND ID IN (
              SELECT DISTINCT ID
                FROM TBL_INFO
               WHERE FLAG='No'
            ORDER BY ID
               LIMIT 3
             )


Hi @MatBailie, I've tried ur solution, but it only updates 2 distinct ids.

Your sample table contains 5 distinct IDs (012, 123, 456, 574, 789) and you want to filter out first three ids which contains flag='No'.
So, use MySQL script:
WITH T AS (
  SELECT id,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY id) as row_num
    FROM TBL_INFO
    where UPPER(flag) = 'NO'
    group by id
    ORDER BY id
)
SELECT * FROM T WHERE row_num <= 3

Which returns your id information: ['012', '123', '574']
Now your final query should be:
WITH T AS (
  SELECT id,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY NULL ORDER BY id) as row_num
    FROM TBL_INFO
    where UPPER(flag) = 'NO'
    group by id
    ORDER BY id
)
UPDATE TBL_INFO
    SET flag = 'X'
    WHERE UPPER(flag) = 'NO'
    AND id IN (SELECT id FROM T WHERE row_num <= 3);

Which update 5 matched rows:

and your final output table is:
select * from TBL_INFO ORDER BY id;


Sample Query & result: db<>fiddle

Why add the overhead of the window function, when a simple limit would suffice? Why use UPPER(flag), making this predicate non-SARGable? DISTINCT does nothing here as you are already grouping by id.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. dbfiddle.uk even has a button to export the data, messages, etc, as markdown...

@user1191247 UPPER(flag) used because of case-insensitive validation of string value 'no'.
Yes, you're right, when I used group by then DISTINCT is not a meaningful.

@MatBailie How I export db<>fiddle output ? I don't see any option...

@ArtBindu The markdown button at the top of the page, next to run.

@ArtBindu OP's sample data shows the flag values consistently with only the first letter capitalised, and there is nothing to suggest a CS collation. You should at least have a caveat explaining the downsides of forcing the column to uppercase.

@user1191247
